# Azure: What Happens to User Session During Swapping VIPs (Virtual IPs)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

What happens to a user session when a new deployment from staging is swapped (Virtual IP - VIP - is swapped) to production and the old production moves to staging?

Does a user session stay in production all the time (in this case running against new production) or does it stay for some time with the old production that moved to staging?

Thank you for comments.

Learner.For.Ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

websites have two names - sitename and sitename-staging (not necessarily, you can connect it with your domain name). VIP Swap operation invokes the operation that swaps a virtual IP address swap between the staging and production deployment environments. I did some research, and existing connections should preserve (RDP worked, for example). So, returning to your question - existing connections should work, but i would not rely on that and do the swap whenever it is most quiet with your solution.

Comment: so what you are saying is that a user session is terminated at the time of swapping VIPs.  Correct?

Comment: Sorry, missed your question. According to my research, existing sessions were not terminated, at least immediately. I see no reason why they should be terminated, but i can not say or guarantee that for sure. :-)

Comment: Thanks Alex for your comments.  Learner.For.Ever

Comment: If that answer was helpful, please mark the question as answered, or add details if you need additional information. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm a newbee here so cannot mark yet as answer as I need to gather enough points... Maybe someone else can mark it as answer.  Thanks Alex

Comment: No, only the person asked the question is able to do that. Anyway - if you need any clarification, would be happy to help.

Comment: @Learner.For.Ever btw, just had the pleasure of reading the official documentation on how the process looks like and remembered that you asked that question - i hope, you will find what you  did look for - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-site-swaps